# How to remove ui view after cell tap?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom xib table view cell that has a green uiview on it. The uiview acts as a new message indicator - whenever a message comes in, the green view is displayed. When a user taps the cell, I want to set the view to hidden.

My only question is; how would I go about hiding the view just on that specific table view cell and not all table view cells?

Comment: Show us, what did you already tried?

Comment: Implement the "tap and remove green view" ***inside*** your cell class. Then use a closure (preferred) or protocol/delegate pattern to update your **data** so the green view is not displayed again when you scroll away from and back to that cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the reference of the cell that should hide the green view as follow:

```
guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: yourRowIndex, section: yourSectionIndex)) as? YourCustomTableViewCell else { return }
    cell.greenView?.isHidden = true
```

and hide the green view with the `isHidden` property set to `true`.
Of course you have to provide the right `IndexPath` for your specific cell, for instance if you want to hide the green view of the third cell at the second section your `IndexPath` would be `IndexPath(row: 2, section: 1)` and then cast the cell to your specific cell type.

Comment: This will hide the `greenView` in the cell... but it won't **stay** hidden. Scroll that cell out of view, then back into view, and the `greenView` will once again be visible.

Comment: Yes, on a scrolling tableview this is the behavior. The cell should have a state reference that could be changed with a closure, a delegate or an external state passed as a parameter in the cellForRow